# Creating 2 child process that alternates

Tags: c, operating-system

How can i write a program that creates two child processes using a fork. The first child has to print even numbers (between 2 and 10), and the other, odd numbers (from 1 to 9). The program should display the numbers on the screen in ascending order. To achieve this, the executions of the two children must alternate.

Comment: Two semaphores.  Swap a 'go' unit between the processes.  Giga-dupe:(

Comment: Use a locking mechanism to lock on of the child processes, or thread the main process and lock access to the shared printing method.

Answer (score 1):

The are a lot of ways for achieving your desired result, like mutexes, semaphores and signals, in this example i will use signals (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html for documentation):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define ERROR(m) perror("Error while: "#m); \
  return 1;

void handler(int sig){
  // do nothing
}

int main(void){
  pid_t child_pid;
  pid_t parent_pid;
  struct sigaction sa;
  parent_pid = getpid();

  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_handler = handler;
  sa.sa_flags = 0;
  if(sigaction(SIGUSR1,&sa,NULL) == -1){
    ERROR("sigaction()");
  }

  switch(child_pid = fork()){
  case -1: // in case of error
    ERROR("fork()");
  case 0:  // child
    for(int number = 2; number <= 10; number += 2){
      pause(); // waiting for any type of signal
      printf("Child: %d\n",number);
      kill(parent_pid,SIGUSR1);
    }
    break;
  default:  // parent
    for(int number = 1; number <= 9; number += 2){
      printf("Parent: %d\n",number);
      kill(child_pid,SIGUSR1);
      pause();
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

## OUTPUT:

```
Parent: 1
Child: 2
Parent: 3
Child: 4
Parent: 5
Child: 6
Parent: 7
Child: 8
Parent: 9
Child: 10
```